# How to Handle All gestures

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, ios7, uigesturerecognizer

In my iPad project i have to make
**1.Tap gesture
2.Swipe right and Swipe left Gesture
3.Single Finger Pan Gesture
4.Two finger Pan gesture. 
5.Long press gesture**

I don't know how to handle all these gestures.When Long press gesture is used only Swipe right gesture and two finger Pan gesture has to work. App gets confused at these many gestures in a single screen. How to Handle everything easily. Please help

Answer (score 1):

Firstly i will say your question was little confusing and we can easily add multiple UITapGestures on a singleView without any prob. The OS automatically detects which gestures you are doing. There are many tutorials for that. Look at these links, if you still can find any solution, tell me may be i can try a code piece for u.

[Link 1](http://www.edumobile.org/iphone/iphone-programming-tutorials/gesture-recognizers-in-ios/)

[Link 2](http://www.icodeblog.com/2010/10/14/working-with-uigesturerecognizers/)

and lastly

[Link 3](http://www.appcoda.com/ios-gesture-recognizers/)